# HYPERLINK formula for new record

Tags: apex, visualforce, formula-field, hyperlink

Could not find a way to display HYPERLINK formula field on my custom visualforce edit screen when create a NEW record:

in standard controller extension I use recalculateFormula

```
currentRecord.recalculateFormulas();
```

on visualforce page I use output field

```
<apex:outputField value="{!currentRecord.IBANLink__c}"/>
```

formula field itself:

```
HYPERLINK('https://www.iban.com/', 'IBAN Check')
```

Again: editing of already existing records works good. I encounter the problem only when try to create new record

**UPD:** *Please see screenshot of corrupted hyperlink-formula on VF page:*

[image]

Comment: This is because, when you are creating a new record the record is not created yet and there is no value assigned to the formula field. What is your actual requirement?

Comment: Why would you use a formula field for a value that will be exactly the same on all the records? Why not use the Custom Setting instead? This way you would work around the problem that was explained in the previous comment, meaning you could reference the value from the Custom Setting even before the new record is created.

Comment: @SarojBera is to see field formula result before record is creted

Comment: @dinoursic this formula supposed to be dynamic - generate link based on data provided

Comment: I forgot to attach a screenshot of how hyperlink-formula-field looks like after doing .recalculateFormulas(); in apex